# How to keep UIKeyboard when textfield is regisned first responder?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboard, first-responder

I'm writing an app that has a view similar to the SMS app's text editing view. It has a textview on the top and a textfield on the bottom. I want to allow users to copy and paste texts in the textview while keeping the keyboard appear. But if I try to copy the text, the UITextField will resign first responder and the keyboard will missing. Any ideas about how can the SMS app keep the keyboard while user is copying texts in another view?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

I've tried to `return NO` for `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:` , but the textview to the upper cannot copy text then.

Comment: Did you solve this? Im looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Related Option:

Just Give a button on Topbar or anywhere else that have option to copy the text then its more user friendly..

Second Option:
If you have much good know programming concepts then just create the new view above the keyboard and animate when keyboard is show and don't resignfirstresponder, and following options are their, copy text, done, in the done action you have resign first responder

Those are only option which u have done if you want more userfriendly app because in appStore and appReview Department have verify the User Convenience UI Integrations and you must full fill that and from the other side user's whom purchase or download the app also give the awesome comments on the app who is more reliable and cashless functionalities ....

> I've tried to return NO for -(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing: , but the textview to the upper cannot copy text then.

*add a textfield so it can scroll and set the dimentions or just add the scrollbar to scroll it to .. it will solve your problem*

Comment: Actually I can animate down the textfield before copy and show keyboard before paste, but I just wonder how apple can allow the SMS app to show keyboard while textfield resigned first responder. Maybe my only option is to hide & show keyboard...

Comment: yes you can if its not meet other options then you can hide and show the keyboard but its not the good way .. but if case study meet up your requirement then go ahead and do it.. because in some case developer also stuck for the SDK features.. :(